# Error in Python Method. Lists

Tags: python, list

I'm new to Python. I'm writing a simple class but I'm with an error.

My class:

```
import config   # Ficheiro de configuracao
import twitter
import random
import sqlite3
import time
import bitly_api #https://github.com/bitly/bitly-api-python

class TwitterC:
    def logToDatabase(self, tweet, timestamp):
        # Will log to the database
        database = sqlite3.connect('database.db') # Create a database file
        cursor   = database.cursor() # Create a cursor
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS twitter(id_tweet INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, tweet TEXT, timestamp TEXT);") # Make a table
        # Assign the values for the insert into
        msg_ins       = tweet
        timestamp_ins = timestamp
        values        = [msg_ins, timestamp_ins]
        # Insert data into the table
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO twitter(tweet, timestamp) VALUES(?, ?)", values)
        database.commit() # Save our changes
        database.close() # Close the connection to the database

    def shortUrl(self, url):
        bit = bitly_api.Connection(config.bitly_username, config.bitly_key) # Instanciar a API
        return bit.shorten(url) # Encurtar o URL

    def updateTwitterStatus(self, update): 
        short = self.shortUrl(update["url"]) # Vou encurtar o URL
        update = update["msg"] + short['url']
        # Will post to twitter and print the posted text
        twitter_api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=config.twitter_consumer_key, 
                          consumer_secret=config.twitter_consumer_secret, 
                          access_token_key=config.twitter_access_token_key, 
                          access_token_secret=config.twitter_consumer_secret)
        status = twitter_api.PostUpdate(update) # Fazer o update
        msg    = status.text # Vou gravar o texto enviado para a variavel 'msg'
        # Vou gravar p a Base de Dados
        self.logToDatabase(msg, time.time())
        print msg

x = TwitterC()
x.updateTwitterStatus([{"url": "http://xxxx.com/?cat=31", "msg": "See some strings..., "}])
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\anlopes\workspace\redes_soc\src\twitterC.py", line 42, in <module>
    x.updateTwitterStatus([{"url": "http://xxxx.com/?cat=31", "msg": "See some strings..., "}])
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\anlopes\workspace\redes_soc\src\twitterC.py", line 28, in updateTwitterStatus
    short = self.shortUrl(update["url"]) # Vou encurtar o URL
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Any clues on how to solve it?

Best Regards,

Comment: remember you can also upvote good answers (like I just did for Steve), and if it's checkmarked, I presume it's good. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your call to updateTwitterStatus just needs to lose the square brackets:

```
 x.updateTwitterStatus({"url": "http://xxxx.com/?cat=31", "msg": "See some strings..., "})
```

You were passing a list with a single dictionary element.  It looks as though the method just requires a dictionary with "url" and "msg" keys.

In Python, `{...}` creates a dictionary, and `[...]` creates a list.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you everything you need to know. It says "list indices must be integers, not str" and points to the code `short = self.shortUrl(update["url"])`. So obviously the python interpreter thinks `update` is a list, and `"url"` is not a valid index into the list.

Since `update` is passed in as a parameter we have to see where it came from. It looks like `[{...}]`, which means it's a list with a single dictionary inside. Presumably you intended to pass just the dictionary, so remove the square brackets when calling `x.updateTwitterStatus`

The first rule of debugging is to assume that the error message is correct, and that you should take it literally.